# Etherscan how to get latest transactions?

Tags: transactions, etherscan

I am using [this](https://api-ropsten.etherscan.io/api?module=account&action=txlist&address=0x25BEADE120E501D7b984498D196eFe4AbE6a11F6) api to get all transactions at an address, however I see it returns the last 1000 transactions, is there any way to make it return first 1000 transactions by date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `&sort=asc` to the end of the query: https://api-ropsten.etherscan.io/api?module=account&action=txlist&address=0x25BEADE120E501D7b984498D196eFe4AbE6a11F6&sort=asc

Comment: It did not worked, the timestamp is same with or without sort for the first and last result

Comment: For me it returns the oldest transactions when I specify `sort=asc` and the newest for `sort=desc`.  Though, `sort=asc` seems to be default behavior, i.e. without `sort` parameter it returns me the oldest transacitons as well.

Comment: Aah, I get it, I wanted the latest, so desc works.